# Find a file in my directory

Tags: c#, path

I need to get the path of a file which is in a specific directory.The user selects a csv file from a OpenFileDialog. If the csv file has field that ends at .txt then take the path of that file and put it in a pathfile variable. The new file has to be placed, by the user, in the same directory as the csv file.

**EDIT:** *How do I put the path of the file in a variable ?*

**EDIT2:** The file could be placed everywhere, for example: `C://george.csv`. So I want to take a txt from the directory `c://` .Or if the file is here: `C://Documents/anna.csv`. The text has to be `C://Documents/textfile.txt`.

**EDIT3:** The csv file that the user has opened is at `c://Documents/gonow.csv` 
The file gonow.csv is :    `one, two, tree, four, textfile.txt, five, six, seven`. 
When a field has extension .txt then the program has to go and cath the path. In this case the path is `c://Documents/textfile.txt`.

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string filename = "";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filename = openFileDialog2.FileName;
                textBox3.Text = filename;
                System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox3.Text); 
}
}

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
        if (Path.GetExtension(colB[j]) == ".csv")
       textBox2.Text += " comma separated, in line " + j + "" + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question/problem beside your requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
```

**EDITED according to your EDIT3:**
Use this function to open your csv file and get new complete filename.

```
private string GetFilename(string csvFilename)
{
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(csvFilename);

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFilename);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] items = line.Split(',');
        string txt = items.First(item => item.ToLower().Trim().EndsWith(".txt"));
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt)) 
            return Path.Combine(path, txt);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: @george mano: tell us clearly what do you need. You asked _"How do I put the path of the file in a variable ?"_ and I've just answered. So, what's wrong?

Comment: It worked adding these lines in my code. `string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text);
                         string g= Path.Combine(path, colB[j]);  textBox2.Text += "path is :  " +g + " " + Environment.NewLine;` Your code made some exceptions and I didnt use it.

Answer (score 0):

iF you need to put the txt file (the generated file) in the same folder as that of the CSV file, you can store the path of the CSV file and create the txt file in theat folder.

To do this you may like to have a variable like this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "";
        string FolderPath;
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = openFileDialog2.FileName;
            FolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
            textBox3.Text = filename;
            System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox3.Text); 
        }
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(colB[j]) == ".csv")
            textBox2.Text += " comma separated, in line " + j + "" + Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

The FolderPAth variable holds the path to the folder. You can create the txt file in this folder. This means that the txt file is in the same folder as of the csv file. If you need to access this in a different method, you may declare it in relevant scope.